# Proving that $\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{a}{b}\right)$, with conditions on integers $a$, $b$, $n$, and prime $p$, is never an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have painstakingly proven that an object that I'll call $f_p$ has the form:
$$f_p=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{a}{b}$$
with $a,b,p\in\mathbb{N}$ and $gcd(p,b)=1$ such that $p$ is a bigger prime than all primes that make up the prime factorization of $b$. Moreover $\frac{a}{b}$ cannot be an Integer.

There are some bounds such that $p\geq 5$ and $a,b>1$.

Clearly $f_p\in\mathbb{Q}$. I am struggling to prove that:
$$f'_p = \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}f_p$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>2$ is also rational and never an integer. I mean, if $f'_p$ were to be a natural number $M$ then:
$$M\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{a}{b}$$
which doesn't seem possible but can't seem to prove why.

It is clear that if $p$ is in the prime factorization of $n$ then $f'_p$ is not integer, however, if $p$ and $b$ are in the prime factorization of $n^2-1$ then:
$$n^2-1 = kp^\alpha b^\beta\qquad \alpha>0,\beta\geq0$$
and so:
$$f'_p = \frac{k}{n^2}\left(p^{\alpha-1}b^\beta+p^{\alpha}b^{\beta-1}a\right)$$
Then $k(p^{\alpha-1}b^\beta+p^{\alpha}b^{\beta-1}a)
$ should be divisible by $n^2$ such that:
$$k\,\frac{p^{\alpha-1}b^\beta+p^{\alpha}b^{\beta-1}a}{n^2}\in\mathbb{N}$$
but that would entail that since $n^2 = kp^\alpha b^\beta+1$:
$$k\frac{p^{\alpha-1}b^\beta+p^{\alpha}b^{\beta-1}a}{kp^\alpha b^\beta+1}\in\mathbb{N}$$
again I am stuck here.

Comment: Counterexample: $\ \dfrac{2^2-1}{2^2}\left(\dfrac{1}3+\dfrac{1}1\right)=\dfrac{3}4\,\dfrac{4}3= 1\in\Bbb Z\ \ $

Comment: Oh god I forgot to put some bounds on $n$ and $p$ especially. I am sorry!

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: $\frac{22² - 1}{22²} \left( \frac{1}{23} + \frac{925}{21} \right) = 44 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am sorry but $a/b$ cannot be an integer. Maybe I should have been clearer in the question

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Man you are a monster. Do you use mathematica or something like it?

Comment: I didn't use any computer programs, just looked for suitable positive integers $a, b, n$ and a prime $p$ for which $(n-1)(n+1)(b + ap)$ is divisible by $bpn²$. I thought that letting $b = n-1$ and $p = n+1$ would lead us to an easy solution.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear that!